# Trouble with wired connection

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, network-manager

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and having problems connecting to a wired connection. My computer is having problems connecting to the network. Up until now, I have been able to solve this problem by doing the following: Restart the router then unplug/replug the network cable from my computer. I would have to do this every time I booted up my machine, and it would be able to connect to the internet just fine (until I rebooted my machine again, in which case I would need to do this again).

This stopped working today. No matter how many times I restart my computer or the modem, or unplug/replug network cables, I can't connect to the network. The computer detects that a wired connection is *there*, but just doesn't connect.

Viewing the Network Connections window, it shows:

> Name: Wired connection 1; Last Used: now

It's not a hardware problem (at least with the modem or cable), because it works just fine if I plug in a different computer.

The file `/etc/network/interfaces` is currently at its default:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I've found many instances of similar problems on askubuntu, where the problem was fixed by changing this file to:

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

but this change does not fix the problem for me.

Here is what `ifconfig` shows:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:d1:e2:19:b5  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1973 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:14070 (14.0 KB)  TX bytes:388391 (388.3 KB)
      Interupt:20 Memory 90300000-90320000

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1981 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1981 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:414704 (414.7 KB)  TX bytes:414704 (414.7 KB)
```

Comment: Please put back the `interfaces` file back to its default and save the file. Once done, open a terminal & run `tail -f | dmesg`, let it run. While doing so, open up another terminal, then run `sudo ifdown eth0` & again `sudo ifup eth0`. Then please refer to the log on the other terminal. Post it here if there's any suspicious activity.

Comment: And what AzkerM means by "suspicious activity" is: anything that mentions `eth0`

Comment: I was too frustrated with the computer, so I left the office early and headed home for the weekend. I'll try this on Monday.